# I want to know the reason why we should use 'the' in this case

Tags: determiners

1. There is a pencil on *the* desk.
2. He is in *the* room.

In the sentences above, why should we use 'the' in the preposition phrase?
What is the meaning of 'the' in this case?

Comment: **The** indicates a *particular* member of the class.  A particular desk.  A particular room. Not just any desk, not just any room.

Answer (score 4):

It does not have to be "the" but you need some determiner.  You could not say "there is a pencil on desk" but you could say "there is a pencil on a desk" and you could also use "this" or "my" or "your" or many other words.

"The" marks a specific desk; usually, it  will be clear from context which desk is meant.

Comment: More to the point, it implies that the it is a desk which has already been mentioned, or is otherwise known to the hearer.

Comment: @Colin - Generally so, although there are some interesting exceptions. For example: _The lion is the king of the jungle. Music tames the savage beast. A bird in the hand beats two in the bush. What I need is a nice vacation on the beach._

Comment: @J.R.: you're right, there are other uses of "the". But this is the ordinary one.